# Стрелочка назад | Kotlin | Android

Tags: android, kotlin, menu, navigation

У меня есть 2 activity. После перехода с первого на второй, я хочу отображать в AppBarLayout стрелочку назад, которое вернет меня в первое activity. Как это сделать?

P.s: мне нужно это, потому что кнопка "назад" переключает моё меню, что расположено в самом activity.

Comment: https://overcoder.net/q/1019672/добавить-значок-слева-от-заголовка-в-панели-действий-в-android

Comment: @Анастасия, предлагаете просто добавить стрелочку и её обрабатывать? Разве нельзя реализовать это менее костыльными методами.

Comment: Если мне нужна стрелка "назад", которая бы вела меня на родительский активити,я обычно использую метод setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true) для ActionBar и указание родительского активити в манифесте

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если вы используете `ActionBarActivity` то вы можете задать эту стрелочку следующим образом:

```
Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.my_toolbar);
setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
```

После чего вызвать:

```
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
```

Так же вы можете использовать это и из фрагмента:

```
((ActionBarActivity) getActivity()).getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
((ActionBarActivity) getActivity()).getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
```

Если же вы не используете `ActionBarActivities` или вы хотите установить стрелочку "Назад" на `Toolbar-e` который не использует ваш `SupportActionBar` тогда вы можете сделать это так:

```
actionBar.setNavigationIcon(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_action_back));

actionBar.setNavigationOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
   @Override
   public void onClick(View v) {
       // Здесь вы можете обработать ваш клик
   }
});
```